# Storing Time in MongoDB's 64bit Date type in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Using Mongomapper, I'm trying to store the date of each document in a timestamp with milliseconds since epoch. For the life of me I can't figure out how to generate this timestamp in ruby. The 32bit Timestamp datatype isn't precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

`Time.now` should work just fine. The default `to_s` implementation on Time doesn't display fractional seconds, but the data is there (Try `Time.now.usec`). As far as I can tell, mongomapper will preserve this information as best it can when inserting the data into mongo.

There may be some small loss of information because mongodb stores dates as an integer number of milliseconds from the epoch whereas ruby stores nanoseconds since the epoch. Of course the clock on your machine probably isn't accurate enough for that to matter.

Comment: Okay, is this with storing it as a _Date_ or _Time_ key with Mongomapper?

Comment: I'd use Time although i'm not sure it would make a difference

Comment: Actually using Date would through away everything other than year-month-day

Comment: Right that's what I saw between the two. So what should I use to input into a _Time_ data type? The plan is to retrieve documents from a DB by time after a certain date.

Comment: So when using Time.now as normal, will it sort by milliseconds?

Comment: I see you're correct, it does keep track of milliseconds, as I can pull usec from the object. I'm assuming this is taken into account when querying.